# libGDX - If I play a Sound, my Android-Phone stutters/have a micro lag

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx, lag

I'm new in libGDX and if I play a Sound, I have a micro stutter/lag.
My File has the ".wav" extension. - I already tried:

- change the file-extensions
- make the file-duration longer

I appreciate your help! :))

have a nice day

Comment: show some code snippet ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Sure: https://hastebin.com/oqujiyarof.cs - that is all

Answer (score 1):

Recommend setting up an asset manager that loads the sound once before it is needed.  This will allow for reuse and encapsulating the process of loading assets for all or parts of an application.  Recommend strongly against recreating (reloading) the sound each time.  Wave or ogg both work well.  Some articles / posts recommend changing the size.

Answer (score 0):

Create object or decode `Sound` file at once inside `create()` or in `show()` method and play that sound whenever you required.

```
private Sound hit;

@Override
public void create() {

   hit = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sfx_hit.wav"));
}

public void playSound(){
   hit.play(0.5f);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
   hit.dispose();       // <- only dispose when you're no using further 
}
```

Possible reason : Decoding a compressed file takes times so avoid to decode file each time when you want to play sound and Sample rate of your clip should be lower for fast processing.